# How to animate an Animation in Android

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-drawable

i want to ask  that i want to make this animation as single image and wanted to apply some other view animation on it like move or alpha etc. how this can be done ? any idea ? simply i wanted to apply view animation on drawable animation.

i have some drawable like s1,s2,s3,s4 to s16 the XML is

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s3" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s12" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s13" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s14" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s15" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/s16" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

and java code is

```
anim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.black);
   anim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smurf);
    AnimationDrawable hello = (AnimationDrawable) anim.getBackground();
    hello.start();
```

here smurf in drawable is the xml file for drawable animation.

Comment: please any answer or comment

Comment: take a look at this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: Thanks but i want to encapsulate frame animation in tween animation.

Comment: is there any other animation which can be apply on frame animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do that animation but we have to maintain handler for that.

```
    private int index = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private AnimationDrawable drawable;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable.getFrame(index));
        index++;
        if (index == drawable.getNumberOfFrames()) {
            index = 0;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, drawable.getDuration(index));
    }
};
```

in your onclick or where you want to start animation write like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, drawable.getDuration(index));
```

and your `onDestroy()` remove the handeler call backs like this:

```
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

Comment: is my answer is helpfull to you?